# Подсказка в ссылке "откат" о сбросе отметок "оскорбление"

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, локализация, правки, тревоги

Заметил такую странную подсказку к ссылке "откат" при просмотре ревизий:

[image]

Это трудности перевода или всё верно, но я не понимаю о чем речь?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Представьте следующий сценарий:

1. Публикуется сообщение (вопрос или ответ) с нормальным содержимым. (Это версия 1).
2. Некто редактирует сообщение и добавляет туда нечто оскорбительное. (Версия 2).
3. Один или несколько участников отмечают сообщение тревогой "невежливый или оскорбительный". При этом, в частности, Дух Сообщества каждый раз голосует против сообщения.
4. Любой участник (автор сообщения или другой) откатывает содержимое к версии 1.
5. Теперь отметки тревоги стали неактуальны - они относятся к правке, которая была отменена последующей. Удалять сообщение больше не нужно и голоса против от Духа тоже устарели. Пора их отменить. Эта отмена происходит автоматически.